# Can not playback the content on Chrome, where as it plays back on Safari Browser

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, mp4

I recorded a video using a GStreamer pipeline and trying to playback on Chrome(v114.0.5735.90 on MacOS/x86) and Safari(16.4). I neither see any video nor hear audio with this content on Chrome. Attached media-internals snapshot shows the error "Failed to send audio packet for decoding." Not sure what to make of it? Safari is totally happy playing it back.

Here is how my pipeline looks like:

```
gst-launch-1.0  -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.17.197.184:554/0/preview latency=800 ! rtph264depay !  h264parse ! queue ! mp4mux  name=mux streamable=true  fragment-duration=100 ! filesink location=t.mp4  rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.17.197.184:554/audio latency=800 ! rtpmp4adepay ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, channel-layout=MONO, mpegversion=4, layer=3, channels=2, bitrate=64000, stream-fomat=raw ! queue ! mux.
```

Here is my simple video player to play the content. Originally, I saw something similar in a larger context with MSE Player. So, I simplified it a bit using the following Player. Symptoms are very similar in both cases.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video controls="controls" width="320" height="240" source src="t.mp4#t=0" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42801E, mp4a.40.2" muted="false" autoplay="true" preload="auto">
</video>
```

[image: media-internals output]

Comment: Hmm..after posting the question, I realized I can not attach the relevant video in Stack Exchange. :-)